# Scheduling a cron job for a particular time

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to run a particular PHP script using CRON and PuTTy on everyday at 10.30pm. I have managed to run this script in every 5 minutes by this following statement

```
*/5 * * * * curl http://myserver.com/test/test.php
```

This script enables me to run test.php on every 5 minutes but I want it to run everyday 10.30 pm. Can anyone please help me with this situation. This is first time am working with CRON JOB.

Comment: `30 10 * * *` maybe ? But it depends on server timezone, and your local time if it is the same should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
30 22 * * * curl http://myserver.com/test/test.php
```

Cron would be start every day at 10:30pm

Comment: @2kai...should I add a */ in front this statement?

Comment: @user3305327 no need to add anything

Comment: No, you should not. The first parameter is minutes of execution. "30" means "30 minutes". "*/5" means "every 5 minutes". The second parameter is hours. "22" means "22 hours"